# Error In Chat App

Tags: java, swing, sockets, network-programming, event-dispatch-thread

I am newbie to java. I tried to make chat app but some error occur when i run even single client .Why the Text Area and Text Field does not show. What i get is this occurs due to **accept function**  .When compiler reaches to accept function the app become busy. i.e the screen of app show nothing.

**Code Of Client One:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatAppOne{

JFrame jframe;
JTextArea jtextarea;
JTextField jtextfield;
JButton jbutton;

ServerSocket server;
Socket sSocket,cSocket;
InputStream inStream;
ObjectInputStream objInStream;
OutputStream outStream;
ObjectOutputStream objOutStream;


ChatAppOne(){
    jframe=new JFrame();
    jframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    jtextarea=new JTextArea("",28,49);
    jtextarea.setEditable(false);
    jframe.add(new JScrollPane(jtextarea));

    jtextfield=new JTextField();
    jtextfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(440,30));
    jframe.add(jtextfield);

    jbutton=new JButton("Send");
    jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,35));
    jframe.add(jbutton);

    jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try{
                cSocket=new Socket("localhost",1340);
                outStream=cSocket.getOutputStream();
                objOutStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

                objOutStream.writeObject(jtextfield.getText());
                jtextarea.setText(jtextarea.getText() +" \n " +"Me: " +jtextfield.getText());

                jtextfield.setText("");

                cSocket.close();
                outStream.close();
                objOutStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setSize(600,600);
    jframe.setTitle("Chat Application");
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    startServer();
}

void startServer(){
    try{
        server=new ServerSocket(1550);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    while(true){
        try{
            sSocket=server.accept();

            inStream=sSocket.getInputStream();
            objInStream=new ObjectInputStream(inStream);

            String msg=(String) objInStream.readObject();

            jtextarea.setText("App Two : "+ msg);

            sSocket.close();
            inStream.close();
            objInStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new ChatAppOne();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Client Two is same as Client except port difference in server and client.

**Code Of Client Two**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatAppTwo{

JFrame jframe;
JTextArea jtextarea;
JTextField jtextfield;
JButton jbutton;

ServerSocket server;
Socket sSocket,cSocket;
InputStream inStream;
ObjectInputStream objInStream;
OutputStream outStream;
ObjectOutputStream objOutStream;


ChatAppTwo(){
    jframe=new JFrame();
    jframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    jtextarea=new JTextArea("",28,49);
    jtextarea.setEditable(false);
    jframe.add(new JScrollPane(jtextarea));

    jtextfield=new JTextField();
    jtextfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(440,30));
    jframe.add(jtextfield);

    jbutton=new JButton("Send");
    jbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,35));
    jframe.add(jbutton);

    jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try{
                cSocket=new Socket("localhost",1550);
                outStream=cSocket.getOutputStream();
                objOutStream=new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

                objOutStream.writeObject(jtextfield.getText());
                jtextarea.setText(jtextarea.getText() +" \n " +"Me: " +jtextfield.getText());

                jtextfield.setText("");

                cSocket.close();
                outStream.close();
                objOutStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setSize(600,600);
    jframe.setTitle("Chat Application");
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    startServer();
}

void startServer(){
    try{
        server=new ServerSocket(1340);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Started", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    while(true){
        try{
            sSocket=server.accept();
            inStream=sSocket.getInputStream();

            objInStream=new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
            String msg=(String) objInStream.readObject();

            jtextarea.setText("App Two : "+ msg);

            sSocket.close();
            inStream.close();
            objInStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new ChatAppTwo();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ServerSocket code is blocking on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) waiting for a response from the server so the GUI can't repaint itself. You need to execute that code on a separate Thread so the EDT if free to repaint itself and respond to user events.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples. You may find using a `SwingWorker` the easy solution as it manages the Thread for you.